# Force Django related_name return another queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models:

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class CascadedTask(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('tasks.Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cascaded_from')
    cascaded_from = models.ForeignKey('tasks.Task', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Data examples:

model Task:

```
id  name
------------
1   Task #1
2   Task #2
3   Task #3
4   Task #4
5   Task #5
6   Task #6
7   Task #7
```

model CascadedTask:

```
id  task_id  cascaded_from_id 
-----------------------------
1   4        1
2   4        2
3   4        3
4   6        2 
5   6        3
6   6        5
7   7        4
8   7        6
```

My goal is to get QuerySet of `Task` objects but not `CascadedTask` objects when using related_name as it is now:

```
task = Task.objects.last()  # <Task: Task object (7)>
task.cascaded_from.all()  # <QuerySet [<CascadedTask: CascadedTask object (7)>, <CascadedTask: CascadedTask object (8)>]>
```

I would like `task.cascaded_from.all()` return `<QuerySet [<Task: Task object (4)>, <Task: Task object (6)>]>`.

How could I reach that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CascadedTask` model is essentially a [`through` model for a many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). You don't really need it at all:

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cascaded_from = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='cascaded_to')
```

If you do want to retain the model, e.g. in order to add additional attributes, you can follow the aforementioned link's instructions.